# Adding a value to an existing SQL value in a column using C++

Tags: php, c++, sql

How would I make this code snippet add 10 to the value of "goals"?

```
if (buffer.empty())
    break;

buffer.erase(buffer.size() - 1);
async_query("insert into " + db_name("files") + " ("
                           + db_name("player") + ", "
                           + db_name("goals") + ", "
                           + db_name("completed") + ", "
                           + db_name("fid") + ") values " + buffer
                           + " on duplicate key update" + "  "
                           + db_name("player") + " = values("
                           + db_name("player") + ")," + "  "
                           + db_name("goals") + " = values("
                           + db_name("goals") + ")," + "  "
                           + db_name("completed") + " = values("
                           + db_name("completed") + "),"
                           + "  mtime = unix_timestamp()");
buffer.clear();
```

Comment: Try `update files set goals = goals + 10`

Comment: Where would I add that? Or do you suggest I replace the snipet? I need it to remain the same only adding 10 to goals. something like db_name("goals") + 10 +" = values("                                   Would that be correct?

Comment: You need what to remain the same?

Comment: The entire block of code. I am not sure where to add your suggestion.

Comment: Yes, try doing `db_name("goals") + 10` when you are setting the value.

Comment: So it should be async_query("insert into "+ db_name("goals") = 10 + " = values("                                                            Correct?

Comment: Are you trying to set it to 10 or are you *adding* 10 to its current value?

Comment: I am trying to add 10 to the current value.

Comment: Then I think you would need the `update` statement like I showed above.

Comment: How would I add that whilst preserving the function of the rest of the code?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do it without invoking another call to `async_query()`.

Comment: But supposedly invoking another call would complete the funtion and then continue with the rest of the code no? I can add to and modify the code but I need to make sure that the rest of it still works. Could you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: I'm not an expert but I think this should work - `async_query("update files set goal = goal + 10");`

Comment: And I should add that before or after the code snipet?

Comment: Add it after the code snippet (sorry I took so long to reply).

Comment: No worries, I'm sure we all have things to do. Your help is appreciated. I think I have identified the problem. The problem is the c++ buffer function. But I don't know how to remove it.

Comment: how is this related to `php`

Comment: Hi Stan. Do any of the current answers help answer your question "How would I make this code snippet add 10 to the value of `goals`?" I realize you're experiencing further problems with your program, but follow-up questions that extend the original post are not encouraged by Stackoverflow guidelines. If you are having any more problems beyond the scope of your original question you may post another question on the site at any time.

Comment: But for now, can you accept one of the answers here that you believe helped you the most (if any). I will make sure to give them my 500 reputation bounty to them when you do so.

Comment: Because the lifetime of my bounty expires tomorrow, I need to give it to someone before it's too late. You can still accept any answer you like though. I'll give the bounty to whomever in my opinon wrote the best answer. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is pure **MySQL**. It won't work on other SQL engines.

Besides, our question is pretty ambiguous:

Do you want the *new* value of `goals` to be incremented by 10 if the insert hits an existing `fid`, or retain the *old* value and increment it by 10?
Or do you want to put the new value of `goal` + 10 in both cases?

#### A bit of cleanup first

Once the C++ obfuscation removed, your query boils down to :

```
insert into $db_name (player, goals, completed, fid) values $buffer 
on duplicate key update
    player    = values(player), 
    goals     = values(goals), 
    completed = values(completed),
    mtime     = unix_timestamp()
```

(variables have been represented by `$xxx`)

I assume `fid` is the unique index or primary key that will trigger the `on duplicate key`.

I hope you don't have multiple unique indexes, or else the request will possibly modify only the first record that matches the entered values.

Assuming `fid` is the key, what your request do is erase the `player`, `goals` and `completed` fields (and update a timestamp) if a duplicate `fid` is passed.

This seems an ungodly thing to do to me, but surely you have your reasons.

I also wonder why you don't update the timestamp if a new record is created, but that's not the object of your question...

So basically you have 3 possibilities here:

#### 1) set `goals` to new goal + 10 in any case

This would require to tweak the contents of your mysterious buffer, to add 10 to the new goal value.

Your code would then work without other modifications.

#### 2) set `goals` to a new value for a new record, and to the same new value + 10 for an old record

```
insert into $db_name (player, goals, completed, fid) values $buffer 
on duplicate key update
    player    = values(player), 
    goals     = values(goals) + 10, 
    completed = values(completed),
    mtime     = unix_timestamp()
```

#### 3) set `goals` to a new value for a new record, and increment the old goals value by 10 for an old record

```
insert into $db_name (player, goals, completed, fid) values $buffer 
on duplicate key update
    player    = values(player), 
    goals     = goals + 10, 
    completed = values(completed),
    mtime     = unix_timestamp()
```

Since I fail to understand what purpose is served by this query, I leave you the choice of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding the question then this should work, I am not completely familiar with the code used in the question but I feel like I understand what you are trying to do.

Why don't you break this up into two different MySQL query's.  The first one is run on the creation of this record and the second one is run on the updating of the record.  Now because I don't really understand your code I will just write the logic:

```
If the record you are going to insert does not exist, then create it

else if it does exist, get the current value of goals, add 10, the store it in a variable,  Next update the record with the variable holding the new value of goals.
```

I answered this question using my PHP knowledge so I have a feeling I am missing something, so thanks for at least giving this idea a try and please let me know if this really doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Wow first let me say thank you to 0x499602D2 Absolutely amazing thank you for getting others to help me wit this. And secondly I'd like to say thank you to everyone who is trying to help and thanks to this fantastic community. Only 374 charcters left...

Comment: It would seem the problem isn't the sql querey, it is in fact the c++ code that calls the query that fores the values to be overwritten until I figure out what calls the overwrite it will kepp happening no mattewr what.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
async_query("insert into " + db_name("files") + " ("
                           + db_name("player") + ", "
                           + db_name("goals") + ", "
                           + db_name("completed") + ", "
                           + db_name("fid") + ") values " + buffer
                           + " on duplicate key update" + "  "
                           + db_name("player") + " = values("
                           + db_name("player") + ")," + "  "
                           + db_name("goals") + " = values("
                           + db_name("goals") + " + 10)," + "  "
                           + db_name("completed") + " = values("
                           + db_name("completed") + "),"
                           + "  mtime = unix_timestamp()");
```

Note that the `+10` bit happens *inside the sql query*, actually inside the right hand side expression `values()`.  In the php script, it is inside the quotes.